# How to run rspec test cases in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, rspec, rake

I looked for a jenkins plug-in to run rspec test cases in my build workflow. I only found such plug-in for rake. Should I run rspec through a rake task or directly from a shell command?

Is there any other suggested method?

Comment: Both work fine; your choice.